# How to write Levi decomposition of infinite Lie algebra for KP equation?

Tags: lie-algebras

My query is related to [infinite Lie algebra of KP equation](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/27/5/10.1063/1.527129) having commutation relations are given by

$[X(f_1), X(f_2)] = X(f_1\dot{f_{2}}-f_2\dot{f_{1}})$

$[X(f), Y(g)]  = Y(f\dot{g}-\frac{2}{3}\dot{f}g)$

$[X(f), Z(h)] = Z(f\dot{h}-\frac{1}{3}\dot{f}h)$

$[Y(g_1), Y(g_2)] = \frac{2}{3}\sigma Z(\dot{g_1}g_{2}-g_1\dot{g_{2}})$

$[Y(g), Z(h)] = 0$

$[Z(h_1), Z(h_2)] = 0$ here the dots are derivatives with respect to $t$.

In the article, it is proved that the infinite Lie algebra $\left\{{X(f), Y(g), Z(h)}\right\}$ can be written as Levi decomposition of  $\left\{{X(f)}\right\}$ and $\left\{{ Y(g), Z(h)}\right\}$ here later is solvable ideal.

**How I can prove this Levi decomposition ?**